# Socket close vs Inputstream close

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

Class c extends thread

```
static Queue<Socket> socketQueue
Make connection to another server or client
And then add socket to socketqueue
```

Class a extends thread

```
method a
bufferedinputstream bis = socketQueue.poll
Do work
Make bis null without closing it<br>
```

Class b extends thread

```
Method b
Bufferedinputstream bis = socketqueue.poll
Do work
Make bis null without closing it
```

I did make bufferedinput stream null since i do not want to close the connected socket. Several posts were telling me that closing input/output stream would close the socket as well.
Whenever I use input/output stream with socket, I usually close stream and socket if its not null.

What I am trying to do here is to make the socket alive and reuse when input or output stream is needed without connecting again.

I tried socket.shutdowninput and output, however, this throws an exception when i make another input/output stream with the socket.

Is there anything I have misunderstood or am missing at this point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A connection over a socket only ever has one `InputStream` and one `OutputStream`. As soon as you close any of those (or the `Socket` itself) the connection is automatically closed. You need to store the streams you need somewhere and use those, you can not get them from the same `Socket` each time you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there's no way i can make multiple streams with a single connected socket while freely closing one of them and still using the others.

Comment: Right. As said, you need to store the strems somewhere and use them from there; a usual approach is to just use the stored streams whenever you need them. That might be impractical in a multi-threaded scenario but in this case even with multiple streams writing to the same socket you have to take great care to not simply break everything. :)

Comment: You can indeed get them from the socket every time you need them.